# will_paginate can it order by day

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, sinatra, will-paginate

**SCENARIO:** I have a Pictures table that contains hundreds of photos. I'm currently using 'will_paginate' to paginate 100 photos per page. I would like to continue using 'will_paginate' **BUT I want the pagination to be driven by the day.**

I have tried the following by using `sort_by` but I don't think it's working.

`@pics = Picture.paginate(:page => params[:page]).sort_by(&:created_at)`

**END GOAL:**
Home page shows me today's pictures only.
Now if I click on page 2 it shows me yesterdays pictures only.
Now if I click on page 3 it shows me pictures taken from two days ago.

I would like to continue using `will_paginate`

Comment: What happens if there are more than 100 photos for a given date? Let's say you're on page 3 and it's showing the first 100 photos for that date. When you press page 4 will it show the next days's photos? or the current day's photos?

Comment: I guess I should have been much clearer. In my scenario I am showing only 100 photos as I set that to be the maximum default (as that's what you can do as part of the `will_paginate` ). But I DO NOT need it to be 100 AND I DO NOT need a hard set rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use will paginate by group/scope by date. You'll need to do this yourself. It's not terribly difficult though, you could do something like this:

`# pictures_controller.rb`

```
def index
  @date             = Date.parse(params[:date]) rescue Date.today
  @pictures         = Picture.where(:created_at => @date.at_midnight..@date.next_day.at_midnight)

  @total_pictures   = Picture.count
  @current_pictures = @pictures.size
end
```

`# pictures/index.html.haml`

```
- @pictures.each do |picture|
  = #....

= "Showing #{@current_pictures} pictures for #{@date}."
= "There are a total of #{@total_pictures} pictures."

= link_to 'View Previous day photos', pictures_url(:date => @date.prev_day)
- if @date.past?
  = link_to 'View Next day photos', pictures_url(:date => @date.next_day)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarify this very easily. I was hoping I could use the `will_paginate` but this will do.