# rails ,paginate, sort and more than one table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sorting, pagination

I'm new to rails, I want to know how to paginate and sort by a particular column.
I can do this within one table, but when there is more than table, and the sorted column not in the main table.

I have tried many times but failed, and I also searched the web, but also in vain. Now I need your help...help please!

while paginate i'm using this:

```
# encoding: utf-8
  module Pagination
    class Paginator
      attr_reader :item_count, :per_page, :page, :page_param

      def initialize(*args)
        if args.first.is_a?(ActionController::Base)
          args.shift
          ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "Paginator no longer takes a controller instance as the first argument. Remove it from #new arguments."
        end
        item_count, per_page, page, page_param = *args

        @item_count = item_count
        @per_page = per_page
        page = (page || 1).to_i
        if page < 1
          page = 1
        end
        @page = page
        @page_param = page_param || :page
      end

      def offset
        (page - 1) * per_page
      end

      def first_page
        if item_count > 0
          1
        end
      end

      def previous_page
        if page > 1
          page - 1
        end
      end

      def next_page
        if last_item < item_count
          page + 1
        end
      end

      def last_page
        if item_count > 0
          (item_count - 1) / per_page + 1
        end
      end

      def first_item
        item_count == 0 ? 0 : (offset + 1)
      end

      def last_item
        l = first_item + per_page - 1
        l > item_count ? item_count : l
      end

      def linked_pages
        pages = []
        if item_count > 0
          pages += [first_page, page, last_page]
          pages += ((page-2)..(page+2)).to_a.select {|p| p > first_page && p < last_page}
        end
        pages = pages.compact.uniq.sort
        if pages.size > 1
          pages
        else
          []
        end
      end

      def items_per_page
        ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "Paginator#items_per_page will be removed. Use #per_page instead."
        per_page
      end

      def current
        ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "Paginator#current will be removed. Use .offset instead of .current.offset."
        self
      end
    end

    # Paginates the given scope or model. Returns a Paginator instance and
    # the collection of objects for the current page.
    #
    # Options:
    #   :parameter     name of the page parameter
    #
    # Examples:
    #   @user_pages, @users = paginate User.where(:status => 1)
    #
    def paginate(scope, options={})
      options = options.dup
      finder_options = options.extract!(
        :conditions,
        :order,
        :joins,
        :include,
        :select
      )
      if scope.is_a?(Symbol) || finder_options.values.compact.any?
        return deprecated_paginate(scope, finder_options, options)
      end

      paginator = paginator(scope.count, options)
      collection = scope.limit(paginator.per_page).offset(paginator.offset).to_a

      return paginator, collection
    end

    def deprecated_paginate(arg, finder_options, options={})
      ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "#paginate with a Symbol and/or find options is depreceted and will be removed. Use a scope instead."
      klass = arg.is_a?(Symbol) ? arg.to_s.classify.constantize : arg
      scope = klass.scoped(finder_options)
      paginate(scope, options)
    end

    def paginator(item_count, options={})
      options.assert_valid_keys :parameter, :per_page

      page_param = options[:parameter] || :page
      page = (params[page_param] || 1).to_i
      per_page = options[:per_page] || per_page_option
      Paginator.new(item_count, per_page, page, page_param)
    end

    module Helper
      include Redmine::I18n

      # Renders the pagination links for the given paginator.
      #
      # Options:
      #   :per_page_links    if set to false, the "Per page" links are not rendered
      #
      def pagination_links_full(*args)
        pagination_links_each(*args) do |text, parameters, options|
          if block_given?
            yield text, parameters, options
          else
            link_to text, params.merge(parameters), options
          end
        end
      end

      # Yields the given block with the text and parameters
      # for each pagination link and returns a string that represents the links
      def pagination_links_each(paginator, count=nil, options={}, &block)
        options.assert_valid_keys :per_page_links

        per_page_links = options.delete(:per_page_links)
        per_page_links = false if count.nil?
        page_param = paginator.page_param

        html = ''
        if paginator.previous_page
          # \xc2\xab(utf-8) = &#171;
          text = "\xc2\xab " + l(:label_previous)
          html << yield(text, {page_param => paginator.previous_page}, :class => 'previous') + ' '
        end

        previous = nil
        paginator.linked_pages.each do |page|
          if previous && previous != page - 1
            html << content_tag('span', '...', :class => 'spacer') + ' '
          end
          if page == paginator.page
            html << content_tag('span', page.to_s, :class => 'current page')
          else
            html << yield(page.to_s, {page_param => page}, :class => 'page')
          end
          html << ' '
          previous = page
        end

        if paginator.next_page
          # \xc2\xbb(utf-8) = &#187;
          text = l(:label_next) + " \xc2\xbb"
          html << yield(text, {page_param => paginator.next_page}, :class => 'next') + ' '
        end

        html << content_tag('span', "(#{paginator.first_item}-#{paginator.last_item}/#{paginator.item_count})", :class => 'items') + ' '

        if per_page_links != false && links = per_page_links(paginator, &block)
          html << content_tag('span', links.to_s, :class => 'per-page')
        end

        html.html_safe
      end

      # Renders the "Per page" links.
      def per_page_links(paginator, &block)
        values = per_page_options(paginator.per_page, paginator.item_count)
        if values.any?
          links = values.collect do |n|
            if n == paginator.per_page
              content_tag('span', n.to_s)
            else
              yield(n, :per_page => n, paginator.page_param => nil)
            end
          end
          l(:label_display_per_page, links.join(', ')).html_safe
        end
      end

      def per_page_options(selected=nil, item_count=nil)
        options = Setting.per_page_options_array
        if item_count && options.any?
          if item_count > options.first
            max = options.detect {|value| value >= item_count} || item_count
          else
            max = item_count
          end
          options = options.select {|value| value <= max || value == selected}
        end
        if options.empty? || (options.size == 1 && options.first == selected)
          []
        else
          options
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Kaminari gem](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) is a little bit better now than will_paginate. Take a look at that one too.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you tried 'will_paginate' gem? It seems clearer for me than whatever in your code, and it's well-documented.

Here it is, take a look: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paginate elements by quantity, like "100 posts per page", [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) is the best solution, I think.

But the problem appears, if you try to paginate elements by date or so on, when you can't predict, how many elements will be on the page. In this case, I'm using this solution [will_paginate can it order by day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691211/will-paginate-can-it-order-by-day). Works well for me.