# Rails - How to customize kaminari gem so that each page only shows posts with a certain attribute value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, kaminari

Sorry if my title is a bit iffy

I have installed Kaminari and used the bootstrap3 theme for it (if that matters). It's a pretty nifty gem and I understand the .per(number) attribute you can attach to your posts_controller

My posts have 3 attributes - :title, :body, :date. Date is an option the user selects when making a new post, it makes sense don't worry about how inefficient it might sound. Trust me on that.

**My question is, can I have kaminari put all the posts with a certain :date in one page, and the following :date in the next one, etc?**

There will only ever be a maximum of 15 posts per date. Some dates may have less however, so I want to organize the posts on each page solely by :date (1/1, 1/2, 1/3 .... 12/31)

I have researched the topic and come across Ajax... I have no idea how to use that so if that's the solution please advise on where I can start.

---

Also bootstrap3 shows a pagination feature here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#optional-disabled-state

I want my pagination to be just like this one, with "Older" replaced with "Previous Day" and "Newer" replaced with "Next Day" or something like that. You get the idea.

I don't know what value to put in the  slot to grab the page :id of the next page. Please advise on that if you can.

Thanks in advance

---

edit: [SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691211/will-paginate-can-it-order-by-day)

So as my friend below mentioned, it's not possible to do this in Kaminari or will_paginate, as far as I can tell. So All I had to do was:

1. I added a new attribute, called day and made it into a :date type. I didn't want to make date into a :date type because that sounds confusing.
2. I updated all the forms where users select the date so that the following code was there:

   > date: <%= f.date_field :day %>

If your browser is updated, this makes it so that a date selector pops up and you can click the date on the map. pretty cool

3. I updated the index method in my posts_controller so all that was in it is this:

   > @date = Date.parse(params[:date]) rescue Date.today
   >   @posts = Post.where(day: @date)
   >   @total_posts   = Post.count
   >   @current_posts = @posts.size
4. I went to my index.html.erb page and in my nav bar I put the following code:

   > @date.prev_day) %>  
   >    @date.next_day) %>

Edit the above to whatever text you want.

Finally, surround the actual posts part of your index page with the following:

```
><% @posts.each do |post| %>  
><% end %>
```

and bobs your uncle! This was actually very cool, and I'm still not sure where the next_day/prev_day methods came from. It works though, so no complaints!

Comment: It looks like this isn't possible with Kaminari: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/issues/402 If you google "rails paginate by date" or similar you'll come up with some solutions, though.

Comment: thanks Jordan. I just found this railscast which is basically the same concept http://railscasts.com/episodes/121-non-active-record-model?autoplay=true